# Failures for Google Apps Script: time based trigger

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am consistently getting a failure report on a time-based trigger I attempted to put into my app script. The script is intended to fire every morning and send out email reminders based on day counts.

I have tried to adjust the script function name that it is calling and change the type of trigger from days to hours.

```
function loops() {

    // Runs at approximately 8:30am in the timezone of the script
    ScriptApp.newTrigger('loops')
        .timeBased()
        .atHour(8)
        .nearMinute(30)
        .everyDays(1)
        .create();

    var report = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
    var emailList = ss.getSheetByName("Email Reminder");

    var data = emailList.getRange(3, 19, emailList.getLastRow() - 1, 24).getValues();
    //Logger.log(data);

    data.forEach(function (row, i) {
        var id = row[0];
        var customer = row[1];
        var user = row[2];
        var URL = row[3];
        var proposedCount = row[4];
        var pendingCount = row[5];


        if (proposedCount == 36) {
            MailApp.sendEmail(user, customer, customer + " has been in the proposal stage for " + proposedCount + " days." +"\n" +"\n" + URL + "\n" + "\nThis is a reminder to keep this job in front of you :)" + "\n" + "\nYour friendly neighborhood accountability partner");
        }
        if (pendingCount == 15) {
            MailApp.sendEmail(user, customer, customer + " has been in the pending stage for" + pendingCount + " days." + "\n" + "\n" + URL + "\n" + "\nThis is a reminder to keep this job in front of you :)" + "\n" + "\nYour friendly neighborhood accountability partner");
        }
    });
}
```

I expect an email to be sent but I keep receiving emails with this error:

> Your script, Email Reminder, has recently failed to finish successfully. A summary of the failure(s) is shown below.
>
> 6/23/19 10:52 AM: myFunction  Script function not found: myFunction   time-based  6/23/19 10:52 AM
>
> 6/24/19 10:52 AM: myFunction  Script function not found: myFunction   time-based  6/24/19 10:52 AM

Comment: Have you changed the name of your function and forgotten to also change your original trigger?

Comment: Joe, `myFunction` is the default function placeholder name from a blank editor.  You need to delete that trigger to stop getting the error message.  Also, if you create a trigger for `loops` within a function named `loops`, you're going to have a positive feedback loop that will keep generating triggers.  Check out the status of your triggers by going to script.google.com -> My Triggers.

Comment: @dwmorrin I will go in and delete that trigger then. So by leaving it the way that it currently shows should work then? I don't need to have a separate function for the trigger?

Comment: @ross that appears to be the problem, I am trying to delete that trigger so the new one appears

Comment: It looks like everything is corrected now. Thank you for the help!

Comment: Whenever you create a trigger like that, I think its worth the trouble to check and make sure that you don't already have one.  Because multiple triggers will fire the functions multiple times.